# Two elements are not equal by using algebraic independent trick

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, field-theory, extension-field, galois-extensions

**Definition**.  $\bar{\Bbb Q}(S)$ denotes an algebraic closure of ${\Bbb Q}(S)$ in $\Bbb R$, that is, $\bar{\Bbb Q}(S)$ is the set of $x\in\Bbb R$ that are algebraic over $\Bbb Q(S).$

It seems that I have trouble with the notation of algebraic closure since I could not figure this question out. Here is my question

> Q. Let $T$ be a transcendental basis and let $x\in\Bbb R$ such that $x\in\bar{\Bbb Q}(S\cup\{t\})$, $S\subset T.$  Now, let $y\in\Bbb R$ such that $y\not\in\bar{\Bbb Q}(E)$ and $|E|\leq |S|+1$, where $E\subset T.$ Then $y\neq x.$

I was thinking to do it by contradiction. Assume  $y=x$. This means, $y\in \bar{\Bbb Q}(S\cup\{t\})$. By definition, we have $y$ is algebraic over $\Bbb Q(S\cup\{t\}).$ But I got stuck here what should I do next? Thank you in advance.

Comment: dear 00GB, what is $E$ here? if $E$ is some arbitrary fixed subset of $T$, then this is not correct as written; for example, take $S=E=\varnothing$ and $x=y=t$. maybe were you given some extra conditions giving a relationship between $E$ and $S$?

Comment: @AtticusStonestrom, Thank you for your comment. $E\subset T.$

Comment: @AtticusStonestrom, let $f\colon \Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ be  a function such that for each $x\in\Bbb R$, $f(x)\in\overline{\Bbb Q(S)}$ where $S$ is a finite $S\subset T$ and $T$ is a transcendental  basis. Can $f$ be suerjective?

Comment: dear 00GB, the answer is in fact no – your condition forces $\operatorname{im}f\subseteq\overline{\mathbb{Q}(S)}$, but this latter set is countable; indeed, since $S$ is finite, the field $\mathbb{Q}(S)$ is countable, so its algebraic closure is countable as well, whence $\operatorname{im}f$ is as well. in particular, since $\mathbb{R}$ is uncountable, $f$ cannot be surjective

Comment: @AtticusStonestrom, I might change a bit but the answer still the same. everything is the same as my last comment but the condition is different. $E\subset T$ be a finite set and for each $x\in\Bbb R$  there exists $e_x\in E$,  we have $f(x)\in\overline{\Bbb Q(S\cup\{e_x\})}$. How about $f$? Still not subjective.

Comment: @AtticusStonestrom, Is it still the same if $E$ is infinite set?

Comment: @00GB As long as $S$ and $E$ in your previous 2 comments are countable, $\overline{\mathbb{Q}(S\cup E)}$ is countable, so $im(f)\subset \overline{\mathbb{Q}(S\cup E)}\subsetneq \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @AtticusStonestrom, did you see my last two comments?

Comment: @EvansGambit, I think it is still true as along as $|T\setminus E|$ is infinite since then $\text{rang}(f)\subset\overline{\Bbb Q(S\cup E)}\subsetneq\overline{\Bbb Q(T)}=\Bbb R$. Is that right?

Comment: @00GB Is $E$ atmost countably infinite, in that case yes. In that case since $T$ is uncountably infinite, certainly, $T-E$ is infinite.

Comment: @EvansGambit, Yes, this is the case. Do you know a book that uses this notation for algebraic closure? I meant, $\overline{\Bbb Q(S)}$